# Auto Pair Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, pairing

I'm developing a system app for rooted devices (installed in /system/app and with root access) in which I need to pair with a bluetooth device automatically. I know some devices such as parrots, bluetooth headsets..etc that have a fixed pin, so I can pair successfully with them without user input.

Now I'm trying to pair with a cell phone. But I've notice that pin changes each time I attempt to pair.

[image]

Is there any chance to get this code programatically so I can use it as pin to pair my device?